# Why does 'lsof' omit system libraries on macOS?

Tags: macos

For reference, this is on macOS Sierra (10.12.6).

As an example, in the terminal, we can execute the following to list the libraries loaded by the current shell:

```
$ lsof -p $$
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
bash    57772 kevin  cwd    DIR    1,4     10370  89692838 /usr/lib
bash    57772 kevin  txt    REG    1,4    969276 101782360 /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.4.12/bin/bash
bash    57772 kevin  txt    REG    1,4    698896 119314050 /usr/lib/dyld
bash    57772 kevin  txt    REG    1,4 662274048 120217216 /private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h
bash    57772 kevin    0u   CHR   16,4  0t566809      1083 /dev/ttys004
bash    57772 kevin    1u   CHR   16,4  0t566809      1083 /dev/ttys004
bash    57772 kevin    2u   CHR   16,4  0t566809      1083 /dev/ttys004
bash    57772 kevin  255u   CHR   16,4  0t566809      1083 /dev/ttys004
```

Note that system libraries are not shown here. However, `vmmap` does confirm that my shell is indeed using (for example) the system's C++ standard library:

```
$ vmmap $$ | grep libc++
__TEXT                 00007fffb9a64000-00007fffb9abb000 [  348K   204K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
__TEXT                 00007fffb9abb000-00007fffb9ae5000 [  168K   148K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
__DATA                 00007fffc3b78000-00007fffc3b80000 [   32K    24K    16K     4K] rw-/rwx SM=COW          /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
__DATA                 00007fffc3b80000-00007fffc3b82000 [    8K     4K     0K     4K] rw-/rwx SM=COW          /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
```

However, on my Ubuntu 16.04 VM, I do see usage of system libraries shown in `lsof` output -- e.g. `libc` is reported here:

```
$ lsof -p $$ | grep libc
bash    2740 kevin  mem    REG    8,1  1868984 2883654 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
```

Is there something I can do on macOS to ensure that system libraries are reported by `lsof`? (Is there some extra flag I should be passing to `lsof`, or is there some other reason why system libraries are not reported here?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're present -- just not in the form you expect. macOS combines most of the common system libraries, including libSystem, into a single object so that they can all be loaded at once. This object is the dyld shared cache (`dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h`), which appears in your `lsof` output.

There isn't a lot of documentation on this process. Interestingly, one of the few sources that *does* talk about it is [the iPhone dev wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Dyld_shared_cache), as iOS uses the same mechanism to avoid having to ship the standalone libraries at all.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to duskwuff's answer (which lead me to discovering this bit of documentation -- thanks!), `man dyld` contains this:

> **DYLD_SHARED_REGION**
>
> This can be "use" (the default),  "avoid",  or  "private".   Setting  it  to
>    "avoid"  tells  dyld  to not use the shared cache.  All OS dylibs are loaded
>    dynamically just like every other dylib.  Setting it to "private" tells dyld
>    to  remove  the shared region from the process address space and mmap() back
>    in a private copy of the dyld shared cache  in  the  shared  region  address
>    range.  This is only useful if the shared cache on disk has been updated and
>    is different than the shared cache in use.

So, if we wanted to see exactly which libraries are loaded + used by a process on macOS, we could launch it with `DYLD_SHARED_REGION=avoid` set. For example:

```
$ DYLD_SHARED_REGION=avoid bash
$ lsof -p $$
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
bash    67924 kevin  cwd    DIR    1,4     6528    588406 /Users/kevin
bash    67924 kevin  txt    REG    1,4   969276 101782360 /usr/local/Cellar/bash/4.4.12/bin/bash
bash    67924 kevin  txt    REG    1,4   523200 108804194 /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
bash    67924 kevin  txt    REG    1,4  2108224 108804181 /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
bash    67924 kevin  txt    REG    1,4    60848 119314060 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
< ... more libraries ... >
bash    67924 kevin  txt    REG    1,4 14249664 119320170 /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
bash    67924 kevin  txt    REG    1,4   436256 119314065 /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
bash    67924 kevin  txt    REG    1,4  1436752 108804146 /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
bash    67924 kevin  txt    REG    1,4   698896 119314050 /usr/lib/dyld
bash    67924 kevin    0u   CHR   16,6 0t462359      1097 /dev/ttys006
bash    67924 kevin    1u   CHR   16,6 0t462359      1097 /dev/ttys006
bash    67924 kevin    2u   CHR   16,6 0t462359      1097 /dev/ttys006
bash    67924 kevin  255u   CHR   16,6 0t462359      1097 /dev/ttys006
```